# Javascript XPATH singleNodeValue get innertext

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I have next function where i read a single node from my XML

```
///
function SelectSingleNode(xmlDoc, elementPath) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return xmlDoc.selectSingleNode(elementPath);
    }
    else {
        var xpe = new XPathEvaluator();
        var nsResolver = xpe.createNSResolver(xmlDoc.ownerDocument == null ? xmlDoc.documentElement : xmlDoc.ownerDocument.documentElement);
        var results = xpe.evaluate(elementPath, xmlDoc, nsResolver, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
        return results.singleNodeValue;
    }
}
```

after I need get value without XML attributes
in IE my next code work fine but in other browsers not

```
SelectSingleNode(xml, "/Param/Group").text
```

in not IE browsers I get value in text, how to get just valid value ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i findout results.singleNodeValue.textContent